# Can S3 GUI client tools steal our aws secret key?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am currently curious about if there any risks when using S3 GUI client tool like S3Browser or Cyberduck to explore our S3 file with AWS secret keys.

https://s3browser.com/

https://cyberduck.io/

Can those aws keys will be stolen by the tool?

Answer (score 2):

Both of these services store the keys locally on your host machine.

From experience I know that S3 Browser allows your credentials to be encrypted locally on the disk using a password of your choosing as the decryption key.

Obviously goes without saying but when using any service ensure the following to increase your security:

- Regularly rotate your credentials.
- Your IAM policies should locked down to the minimum settings you require.
- If you're concerned about API calls enabled S3 API calls in CloudTrail
- If its a 1 time key, immediately remove it afterwards from both the software and your AWS account.

S3 browser also supports the [assuming of a role](https://s3browser.com/amazon-s3-via-assume-role.aspx) which allows it to generate temporary credentials.

Comment: No problem glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is 100% risk free. As a developer who has built one of those [s3 browser](https://www.filestash.app/aws-s3-explorer.html), this is what I'm doing to mitigate the risk:

1. the entire code is 100% open source (https://github.com/mickael-kerjean/filestash) so you can audit the code that actually runs
2. there's a [special page](https://demo.filestash.app/about) from the application that shows the hash of the binary alongside the commit from which this version is built from to enable anyone to see the built they run and verify it as well
3. I support assume role so you can use short lived credentials